# Analysis of data E-learning website

Tags: machine-learning, r, predictive-modeling

Have a dataset of a E-learning company  which have information related to the students demographics, package, payment info, services used, class or grade (KG to 12), login details. 
 If you want i can share the sample data set.
Could anyone help me out in understanding what business value can be derived from this data. I am really confused. I did some analysis was able to find out the max service consumption. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you please share this dataset? I would pretty much appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

Read news articles on schools for inspiration.

- Student achievement compared by demographic
- Student advancement (or lack therefore) across grade
- Class popularity by enrollment
- Average cost per student